# parse.com - Limiting who can sign up

Tags: javascript, security, parse-platform

I might be missing something in the security documentation for parse.com but I don't see how to limit who can sign up to the app?

I am making an app (html/javascript) with parse as the backend. The data will be shared amongst a team of people.

What stops someone from using the sign up javascript [code](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-signing-up) to create their own account with the correct role that then gives them access to the parse database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A requirement to allow only members of a particular team to create an identity (sign up) implies that you have an *external means* of establishing someone's identity as a team member in the first place.

How you get this done with parse's generic (I would argue reasonably generic) User model depends on those external means.  But the effect in parse ought to be, if someone proves they are "on the team", assign their users to an `onTheTeam` role.  Then, via class-level permissions or ACLs, provide more privilege to users who are members of that role and fewer/none to users who aren't.

Here are some ideas about establishing team membership to an externally defined team:

1. If team membership can be established via an api to another system: On a `beforeSave` hook for the `Parse.User`, call that api and assign them to the "onTheTeam" role if successful, otherwise fail with an error.
2. If you know team members' email addresses: Have parse send an email verification challenge to new registrants.  Upon user save, assign them to the "onTheTeam" role if and only if their email is on the list and their `emailVerified` property is true.  (I've used this approach successfully for an app in production).
3. If the team is just a handful of friends: pass everyone a secret via an outside channel.  Have your registration collect name, password and the secret, and assign these to the new user.  Validate the secret in a `beforeSave` hook on `Parse.User`.  If valid, add the user to the "onTheTeam" role, otherwise prevent the save with an error.  (The outside channel you employ to pass the secret depends on the security of your app... e.g. For a highly secure app, ask each team member to meet you at a particular park bench, wear a fedora and pass the secret in a rolled-up newspaper).

Comment: thanks, this clarified it for me - I thought I was missing something! I really like option 3...but both 2 & 3 would work for me. Is there a way for an admin to authorise any sign up requests? So, somebody could send a sign up request but needs admin to authorise it?

Comment: Not built in, but you can do something similar to the other ideas: it all hinges on the idea that the real security in parse is enforced through role membership.  In your last scenario, its easy to signup/login, but the user only gets the role assigned after an admin (who has an admin role) reviews the user and adds it to the team.